# Error Initializing Kafka Producer with Avro Serializer: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I'm having trouble getting a KafkaProducer instantiation to accept an avro serializer for the value serializer config property. I installed `kafka-avro-serializer-5.2.2.jar` with

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=io.confluent -DartifactId=kafka-avro-serializer \
    -Dversion=5.2.2 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=C:/Users/myuser/Downloads/kafka-avro-serializer-5.2.2.jar
```

The jar and related files were added to `~\.m2\repository\io\confluent\kafka-avro-serializer\5.2.2`. I then added the following to my project POM file within dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Then the following imports in my client work fine; code compiles

```
import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
```

But running this:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroSerializer.class.getName());

final Producer<String, Object> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
```

Results in error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/confluent/common/config/ConfigException
```

I found a similar issue tracked [here](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs/issues/318). But I'm not using Kafka Connect. Also

Answer (score 2):

You have to add one more dependency for common config.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
    <artifactId>common-config</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

The class is available in this JAR.

Comment: Thanks. I also needed a few more jars. Answered my own question as I was writing it

Comment: This _should_ be a transitive dependency.

Comment: true, but I think the POM is not having it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by installing additional jar files from confluent: common-config, common-utils, common-utils, and kafka-schema-registry-client.

e.g.

```
$ mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=io.confluent -DartifactId=common-utils -Dversion=5.2.2 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=C:\Users\myuser\Documents\Jars\common-utils-5.2.2.jar
```

Properties filled by renaming .jar -> .jar.zip, Open Archive, navigate to META-INF/maven/.../pom.properties

Then update project POM in a similar fashion.